# Flutter CustomScrollView body is briefly visible before SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I am using a custom scroll view inside some pages that already have a top section and a pinned SliverAppBar within. So the SliverAppBar is not docked at the top of the screen. The problem is that when I scroll, the SliverList can be visible briefly above the SliverAppBar.

[image: image of the list content visible in a 1px line above the SliverAppBar]

The list content is visible in a 1px line above the SliverAppBar.
Here is the code:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: CharacterListAppBar(),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        ),
        child: SearchBar(),
      ), // Search bar
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: Filters(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<Response>(
          future: _characterList,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return CustomScrollView(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                slivers: [
                  const SliverAppBar(
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    toolbarHeight: 8,
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                    pinned: true,
                    primary: true,
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, index) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 24),
                        child: CharacterSlidingCard(
                          character: const {
                            "name": "Gimli",
                            "race": "Nain",
                            "profile": "Warrior",
                            "level": 1,
                          },
                          index: 0,
                          selected: _selectedIndex == 0,
                          onTap: () => _onSelectCard(0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      childCount: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ), // Character list
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CharacterCreationPage.routeName);
    },
    backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColorDark,
    child: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined, size: 40),
  ),
);
```

I have tryied SliverPersistentHeader and SliverOverlapAbsorber with NestedScrollView but the issue is still there.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

**Edit:** Also happens between `SliverAppBar` title and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SliverToBoxAdapter** to Solve this Issue .
Example:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter( 
    child: Container(..),
)
```